# JQuery post to REST service

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have looked at a bunch of different Q/A on stack and I can not seem to solve my issue for why my rest interface is not getting called on the button submit. I would appreciate it if you guys could look and see where the issue could be.

The goal is to have a form input values (for now they are hard coded until I get it to work), and submit to change the database they are in via a REST call.

EDIT: On button click, no errors in console, nothing shows up in DB.

```
<?php 

    $id = "123456";
    $auth = "XYZ123"; //this will change daily
    $url = "http://update/this/id/$id"; //this will change based on user

?>

<script >
    const URL = <?php echo json_encode($url);?>;
    const auth = <?php echo json_encode($auth);?>;
    const data = {
        "flag":"Y" //in the database flag has a value of N want to change to Y
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'auth-key': '${auth}',
            'api-version': '1.0',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'Verbosity' : '4'
        }
    });
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $.post(URL, data, function(data, status){
            console.log('${data} and status is ${status}')
        });
    })
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn">Send it!</button>
```

Comment: You should use the type `button`. Have you tested if the click handler is actually executed? Maybe add a `console.log("Hello world");` above the `$.post(...)` line

Comment: @Kryptur may I ask why button type over submit type? Moving the script to the end seemed to solve this issue and lead to a new one, as Peter below answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript executes before the DOM is loaded (`<script>` tags interrupt the DOM parser). By the time the script executes there is no `.btn` element yet.

Either

- move the script to the end of the body (or at least after the submit button),
- or add the event listener [after the DOM has been loaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/),
- or use the global event listener

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { ... }
  ```

Comment: That makes sense to me, I tried moving the script to the end and then I get a new error which is Access-Control-Allow-Origin, so thank you for helping me move in the right direction.

Comment: So you try to access the API from another URL? Then your API needs to set the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: Do I put the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'url' in the ajaxSetup headers?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header (the server says to the browser "if the current page is under this origin, the request is okay; otherwise reject it, please"). See 
[the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for details.